# Pointer to class member function of template parameter

Tags: c++, xcode, function, templates, gcc

Hi I have a problem to compile my class in XCode, gcc(Apple LLVM compiler 3.0)
I wrote class ContextSchedule it means class which encapsulates list of other class member functions and have no problem to compile it under MSVC++ 2005.

```
template<class T>
class C_ContextScheduler
{
public:
    typedef void (T::*T_EventFunc)();
    typedef std::map<u64, T_EventFunc>  T_EventMap;

public:
    //@ c-tor
    C_ContextScheduler(T & context) : m_Context(context), m_currentTick(0) {};

    //@ Schedule
    //@ funcPtr - pointer to function of class T
    //@ dellayTime in milliseconds - after dellayTime from now will be funcPtr called
    void    Schedule(T_EventFunc funcPtr, u32 dellayTime)
    {
        u64 callingTime = m_currentTick + dellayTime;
        std::pair<int, bool> res = m_eventMap.insert(T_EventMap::value_type(callingTime, funcPtr));
        SC_ASSERT(res.second);
    }  ...
```

Any ideas? Want preserve template way of this solution, thnx.

Comment: What's the error message you get exactly?

Comment: You say you "have a problem", but you don't say *what* problem.

Comment: Template argument for template type parameter must be a type

Answer (score 2):

When the compiler compiles this template, `T` is not yet known. Therefore the exact type of `T_EventFunc` and `T_EventMap` is also not yet known and that compiler doesn't know that `T_EventMap::value_type` will end up being a type. To make this clear, use the `typename` keyword:

```
... = m_eventMap.insert(typename T_EventMap::value_type(callingTime, funcPtr));
```

Comment: great thanx this works:) i supposed something with typename keyword, need to learn something about that. This solution works


`std::pair<typename T_EventMap::iterator, bool> res = m_eventMap.insert(typename T_EventMap::value_type(callingTime, funcPtr));`

Answer (score 0):

Since you don't supply the error you are getting, we can only guess. And my guess is that the result of your insert-call is not correct.

According to [this refernce](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/insert), the return value of `std::map::insert` is `std::pair<iterator, bool>`. Are you sure the iterator is an `int`?

Comment: sorry the i copied test version:(  orig is:
     std::pair<T_EventMap::iterator, bool> res = m_eventMap.insert(T_EventMap::value_type(callingTime, funcPtr));
err:
Template argument for template type parameter must be a type